# JSON Parshing issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I parse JSON value from web service but it gives me this Error:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed (Invalid value around character 3.) UserInfo=0x7f97d5808540 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}`

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLRequest *request = ConstructUrlRequestForuploadImage(DocumentManagementEntityMobileEntity,FileData);

NSLog(@"Response:-%@",request);
NSURLSessionDataTask *getNetworksTask;

getNetworksTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                   {
                       if (error)
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                       NSError *errorReturned = nil;
                       NSLog(@"Responce:-%@",response);

                       //   NSLog(@"Responce:-%@",response);
                       NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&errorReturned];

                       if (!dict) {
                           NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", errorReturned);
                       } else {
                           for(NSDictionary *item in dict) {
                               NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                           }
                       }
```

Please help me on that. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Add your code and a dump of the JSON. But it seems clear that the JSON is incorrect.

Comment: run URL in browser , your response JSON invalid.

Comment: please prefer following Like https://sites.google.com/site/99classroomdiscussion/assignments/json-parsar i think it is helpful to u.

Comment: Add some URL or response that you get from web service.

Comment: What did the NSLog calls print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will occur for empty response array. So you should change the json response format like {status = 1, data = [] }. In your case when there is no data response is []. So this will give an error in json parsing. You can change the status value according to data like 0 or 1.